# USB "Serial" Transceivers (PHY)

Tags: usb, phy, transceiver

I am currently trying to incorporate a Freescale i.mx53 into a design. It has three USB High Speed hosts; one has a built in transceiver, the other two do not (OTG is not part of this discussion).

The other two hosts support the following transceivers (p4478 of the reference manual):

- ULPI (HS/FS/LS)
- Serial (HS/LS)
- IC-USB (FS)

Whilst I would normally use a ULPI, the required pads are being used by other peripherals and therefore I must use of the other PHY options. It connects to a 4-port hub close by one the same PCB.

Problem is, I have no idea who makes them or how to use them. Or if I need special Linux drivers for them. The closest, I've found (I think!) is a [TI TUSB1105](http://www.ti.com/product/tusb1105), but it only supports full-speed, not high speed.

Unfortunately, I know even less about IC-USB and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterChip_USB) isn't really helpful.  Since only full-speed is supported, I can safely ignore this option for the moment.

So, I guess I'm asking:

- Can anyone recommend a serial high-speed USB PHY? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

SMSC makes them:

http://www.smsc.com/index.php?tid=143

XMOS recommends their USB3318 for use with their chips, which implement high-speed USB in software.

Comment: The [USB3318](http://www.smsc.com/media/Downloads_Public/Data_Briefs/3318db.pdf) is ULPI which, as I said, cannot be used in this design because the pins for the bus are already allocated to other purposes.  Is there a mode that I missed?